# Выбор пользователя в OpenSuSe

Tags: загрузка, opensuse, linux

После краха системы, не помню почему при выборе пользователей НЕ показывает список юзеров для выбора тыканием мыши. Память на имена логинов стала очень слабая. Не подскажете как восстановить этот выбор? (*система KDE Plasma 5*)